# Get number equation using specific set of values for get given answer

Tags: math, numbers, mathematical-optimization

I have do it for AI assignment. Need a logic for finding solution ..Here is the explanation of problem  .

I have answer ( any number like for example 10 ). And have some set of numbers (like for example [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]). Now I have to create equation using ( + , - , * , / )  and numbers to get the  answer 10.

This is first step ( not fix length or condition for repeating numbers  ).. there are many solution for this like

5 + 5 = 10 ( 2 step )
2 * 2 = 10 ( 2 step )

2 * 2 + 6 = 10 ( 3 step )
3 * 2 + 4 = 10 ( 3 step ) ...and on

On second step (more difficult )( next assignment after this ) is Have to set some conditions like 
--> must be in specific step ...Or
--> must don't repeater number twice ( if in array here two times 5 than we can use it two times ) 
--> must have to use * twice

I am not too expert in AI But any helpful link will also welcome 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem. Maybe better suited for one of the theoretical computer science Stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly naive solution to the first part is something as follows: Assume all your numbers are rationals. Then just keep performing the allowed operations on your current set of results until you hit your target. There are undoubtedly many ways in which the algorithm can be improved, but this should get you started.

Below is a Python-like pseudocode for a naive solution to the first part.

```py
def solve(numbers, target, binary_operators):
    obtainable_results = set(numbers)
    if target in obtainable_results:
        return True
    while True:
        prev_len = len(obtainable_results)
        for a in obtainable_results:
            for b in obtainable_results:
                for op in binary_operators:
                    c = op(a, b)
                    if c == target:
                        return True
                    obtainable_results.insert(c)
        if prev_len == len(obtainable_results):
             return False
```

Note that it is not immediately clear whether this ever terminates on every input. Can you provide an example of such an input, or prove that this does indeed terminate on all inputs? How can we improve it?

As for the second part, you will also need to maintain your set of allowed conditions as well and their current states. If there are not that many conditions, and they follow simple and similar patterns, then you probably want to do this manually, but if they are many and subject to change, then you might rather want to maintain a set of state machines with respect to each condition for each result.